# Should I add tag that specifies the topic but the asker doesn't know about it?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, editing-help

While reviewing questions I came across this one - [Not able to understand the notations : * and ** with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692986/3132718)
I know these are a pointer and a pointer to pointer so I decided to add this tag to the question. (well, I *suggested* the edit) After that I thought that was not right, since the OP  wouldn't ask the question if knew what `**` means.
Still no one has removed the tag so I think it's not bad to do so, but should I edit tags in such situations or not?

Comment: How should OP tagged the question with this tag if he doesn't know what it is? So it was a good edit, since this will lead the *right* people to the question which then eventually will explain this to OP!

Comment: If you're not sure whether you should edit a question (or its tags) I'd play it safe by just leaving a comment explaining your thoughts. Someone else might pick it up, or the OP might.

Answer (score 1):

It helps future readers if questions are tagged. I also added the tag [dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dereference) to the specific question. If we do it then it will help organize the questions and answers where the OP not necessarily knew exactly what he was asking about or just tagged too few tags.

Maybe it is better to have more tags for questions. An OP is usually more concerned with solving a specific problem than organizing the information for future readers.